# Custom CNN does not have classification report

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am building a model to predict a dataset and my accuracy is really good but I would like to test this by using a classification report but I am really not sure how to fit that into my code. I did not initially think about it but I am in a trouble. Could someone help? Usually, how can we generate the classification report for the custom model?

```
lb = joblib.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/outputs/lb.pkl')

class CustomCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomCNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, len(lb.classes_))
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
        bs, _, _, _ = x.shape
        x = F.adaptive_avg_pool2d(x, 1).reshape(bs, -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

# learning_parameters
lr = 1e-3
batch_size = 32
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

print(f"Computation device: {device}\n")


# read the data.csv file and get the image paths and labels
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/input/data.csv')
X = df.image_path.values # image paths
y = df.target.values # targets
(xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest) = train_test_split(X, y,
    test_size=0.10, random_state=42)
print(f"Training instances: {len(xtrain)}")
print(f"Validation instances: {len(xtest)}")


class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, images, labels=None, tfms=None):
        self.X = images
        self.y = labels
        # apply augmentations
        if tfms == 0:  # if validating
            self.aug = albumentations.Compose([
                albumentations.Resize(224, 224, always_apply=True),
            ])
        else:  # if training
            self.aug = albumentations.Compose([
                albumentations.Resize(224, 224, always_apply=True),
                albumentations.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
                albumentations.ShiftScaleRotate(
                    shift_limit=0.3,
                    scale_limit=0.3,
                    rotate_limit=15,
                    p=0.5
                ),
            ])

    def __len__(self):
        return (len(self.X))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        image = Image.open(self.X[i])
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        image = self.aug(image=np.array(image))['image']
        image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)
        label = self.y[i]
        return (torch.tensor(image, dtype=torch.float), torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long))

train_data = ImageDataset(xtrain, ytrain, tfms=1)
test_data = ImageDataset(xtest, ytest, tfms=0)
# dataloaders
trainloader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
testloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

model = CustomCNN().to(device)
print(model)
# total parameters and trainable parameters
total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
print(f"{total_params:,} total parameters.")
total_trainable_params = sum(
    p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
print(f"{total_trainable_params:,} training parameters.")

# optimizer
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
# loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    optimizer,
    mode='min',
    patience=5,
    factor=0.5,
    min_lr=1e-6,
    verbose=True
)


# validation function
def validate(model, test_dataloader):
    print('Validating')
    model.eval()
    val_running_loss = 0.0
    val_running_correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i, data in tqdm(enumerate(test_dataloader), total=int(len(test_data) / test_dataloader.batch_size)):
            data, target = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
            outputs = model(data)
            loss = criterion(outputs, target)

            val_running_loss += loss.item()
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            val_running_correct += (preds == target).sum().item()

        val_loss = val_running_loss / len(test_dataloader.dataset)
        val_accuracy = 100. * val_running_correct / len(test_dataloader.dataset)
        print(f'Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Val Acc: {val_accuracy:.2f}')

        return val_loss, val_accuracy


# training function
def fit(model, train_dataloader):
    print('Training')
    model.train()
    train_running_loss = 0.0
    train_running_correct = 0
    for i, data in tqdm(enumerate(train_dataloader), total=int(len(train_data) / train_dataloader.batch_size)):
        data, target = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(data)
        loss = criterion(outputs, target)
        train_running_loss += loss.item()
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        train_running_correct += (preds == target).sum().item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    train_loss = train_running_loss / len(train_dataloader.dataset)
    train_accuracy = 100. * train_running_correct / len(train_dataloader.dataset)

    print(f"Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Train Acc: {train_accuracy:.2f}")
```

---I tried to include classification report here but yes, my custom CNN does not have the classification report! the commented part below was my try to see if I can generate a report but I get an error.

```
'''    
    predictions = model.predict(x=xtest.astype("float32"), batch_size=32)
    print(classification_report(ytest.argmax(axis=1),
      predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))
    return train_loss, train_accuracy
'''  

train_loss, train_accuracy = [], []
val_loss, val_accuracy = [], []
start = time.time()
for epoch in range(5):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1} of {epoch + 1}")
    train_epoch_loss, train_epoch_accuracy = fit(model, trainloader)
    val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_accuracy = validate(model, testloader)
    train_loss.append(train_epoch_loss)
    train_accuracy.append(train_epoch_accuracy)
    val_loss.append(val_epoch_loss)
    val_accuracy.append(val_epoch_accuracy)
    scheduler.step(val_epoch_loss)
end = time.time()

print(f"{(end - start) / 60:.3f} minutes")



##
# accuracy plots
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.plot(train_accuracy, color='green', label='train accuracy')
plt.plot(val_accuracy, color='blue', label='validataion accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/outputs/accuracy.png')
plt.show()

# loss plots
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.plot(train_loss, color='orange', label='train loss')
plt.plot(val_loss, color='red', label='validataion loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/outputs/loss.png')
plt.show()

# serialize the model to disk
print('Saving model...')
torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/outputs/sports.pth')

print('TRAINING COMPLETE')
```

Error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleAttributeError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ad111802746a> in <module>()
    157 for epoch in range(5):
    158     print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1} of {epoch + 1}")
--> 159     train_epoch_loss, train_epoch_accuracy = fit(model, trainloader)
    160     val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_accuracy = validate(model, testloader)
    161     train_loss.append(train_epoch_loss)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    777                 return modules[name]
    778         raise ModuleAttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
--> 779             type(self).__name__, name))
    780 
    781     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Union[Tensor, 'Module']) -> None:

ModuleAttributeError: 'CustomCNN' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Comment: that looks like pytorch, not tensorflow

Comment: @Nicolas my bad, wrong tag i fixed it.

Comment: *"predictions = model.predict(x=xtest.astype("float32"), batch_size=32)"* Is this section commented out?

Comment: yes because i wont work, i get the error above if I try that way to show the classification report. Basically that was my try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing it wrong in this line

```
predictions = model.predict(x=xtest.astype("float32"), batch_size=32)
```

Since you are model is in pytorch and it is inheriting the nn.module, you don't need to explicitly call `.predict` to get the predictions because they don't `.predict` functions. `.predict` function is available in tensorflow keras.

You can simply pass the value in model `model(data)` like the below line

```
predictions = []
real_labels = []
for x, y in test_dataloader:
    x = x.to(device).float()
    out_class = model(x)
    label = out_class.cpu().data.numpy().argmax()
    predictions.append(label)
    real_labels.append(y)
```

For calculating the classification_report, you can do the below thing

- Install the seqeval library

  ```
  pip install seqeval
  ```
- Then do the following

  ```
  from seqeval.metrics import classification_report

  predictions = [ predictions ]
  real_labels = [ real_labels ]

  print(classification_report( predictions, real_labels ))
  ```

Make sure the format of `predictions` array and `real_labels` are list of list like  `[ [ class_1, class_2, ... ] ]` thats why I added extra `[ ]` before passing into the function `classification_report'

It will print report something like below

```
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

         ACT       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
    CITATION       0.47      0.82      0.60        11
     SECTION       0.17      1.00      0.29         1

   micro avg       0.38      0.83      0.53        12
   macro avg       0.21      0.61      0.30        12
weighted avg       0.45      0.83      0.57        12
```

where `ACT` , `CITATION` and `SECTION` are the classes or labels in my case.

**EDIT**

By seeing your comment, i guess you are confused as to where you should place the above code, so in the question you have commented some of the lines

```
'''    
   predictions = model.predict(x=xtest.astype("float32"),   batch_size=32)
print(classification_report(ytest.argmax(axis=1),
  predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))
return train_loss, train_accuracy
'''
```

Due to these lines (after uncommenting it) you were getting error. Because you have written `model.predict` .

Just remove these lines and my lines after all the plottings  before this line `# serialize the model to disk`

Comment: Just a small thing: "*you don't need to explicitly call .predict to get the predictions.*" actually `nn.Module`s don't have a `predict` function!

Comment: @coderina so, the code above comes outside of the def fit function or within it?

Comment: @KSp the code comes outside of `fit` function... I suppose you want the classification report after training the model...add the code where you are writing `predictions = model.predict( .... `

Comment: But the issue is I don't have the model. predict in my code. As you can see what Ivan is also saying.

Comment: No no ...in the above code you have commented some lines predictions = model.predict(  just remove those lines and add the lines that I have suggested..   Yes pytorch model doesn't have .predict function, only keras function have I already wrote this in my answer

Comment: @KSp I have edited my code once again, I hope this time its clarifying you as to what I wanted to say

Comment: I get test loader not defined if I replace my commented code with the one you sent.

Comment: I will not be able to use testloader like that since it is inside the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228346/discussion-between-ksp-and-coderina).